# Asp.Net Core MVC JQuery Modal Delete Button Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am new to JQuery and modal pop up windows. I am trying to delete a user and when a user clicks on the bin icon, the modal does appear and I can close it. However, my 'Delete' button does not do anything when I click it. It is like nothing happens while I am clicking it and the post 'DeleteUser' action in the controller is not triggered either. Could you please advise me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing? Thank you in advance!

In my controller:

```
//Deleting a user   
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(string Id)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "The User Account with ID: " + Id + " cannot be found :/";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            return PartialView("_DeleteUserModalPartial", user);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(YouPodApplicationUser user)
        {
            var deletedUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
            if (deletedUser == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "The User Account with ID: " + user.Id + " cannot be found :/";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(deletedUser);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ListUsers");
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
            return View("ListUsers");
        }
    }
```

In my ListUserPages the bin icon for each user:

```
 <td>
                        
                        <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="EditUser" asp-route-userID="@user.Id"> <i class="fa fa-marker fa-lg"></i> </a>

                        <button type="button" class="text-danger ml-1" id="deleteUserModal" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#deleteUser" data-url="@Url.Action($"DeleteUser/{user.Id}", "Admin")" style="border: none; background: transparent"> <i class="fa fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i> </button>
                       
</td>
```

In my DeleteUserModalPartial:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteUser">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteUser">Are you sure you want to delete this user account?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-action="DeleteUser" role="form" id="deleteUserForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="FirstName">First Name: @Model.FirstName</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="LastName">Last Name: @Model.LastName</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="UserName">Username: @Model.UserName</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="userDeleteButton">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In site.js file:

```
//Delete user modal pop up
$(function () {

    var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
        
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {

        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
        $.get(decodedUrl).done(function (data) {

            PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    });


    $("#userDeleteButton").click(function () {
        $("#deleteUserForm").submit();

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just replaced this part:

```
   $("#userDeleteButton").click(function () {
            $("#deleteUserForm").submit();});
```

To the following...

```
PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '#userDeleteButton', function (event) {
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var sendData = form.serialize();
        $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        })
    });
```

And it works! The only limitation now is that I will need to refresh the page for the user to be removed from the list. Any suggestions on this? Thank you!